# How to change the color of a binary image with matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to display a binary image with a specific color.

For now, I create a RGB image with the desired color:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = np.random.normal(0, 10, (20, 20)) > 0 # generate a (20,20) image with random value

binary = image > 0 # create a binary image

binary_rgb = np.zeros(binary.shape + (3,)) #prepare the RGB image

rgb_color = [1, 0, 0] # we choose red for the binary image
binary_rgb[binary,:] = rgb_color

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(binary_rgb)
```

Is there an function in `matplotlib` that would allow to do it easily?

Thanks!

Comment: That is already quite easy. But what about using a specific colormap?

Comment: You could use something like `plt.imshow(binary, cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['black', 'red']))`

Comment: Thanks to Heike and Trilarion, I am not very good at managing colormap, but it appears to be a good approach!